# Create multiple folder if not exists

Tags: powershell

I am trying til make a PS script til create multiple folders from a .csv fil.
It is giving me some problems

This is my code

```
$Folders = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\NewFolders\NewFolders.csv

ForEach ($Folder in $Folders)
{
 If(!(Test-Path $Folder.Path\$Folder.Folder))
  }
  New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Folder.Path\$Folder.Folder
  Write-Host Folder $Folder.Folder created in $Folder.Path ! -ForegroundColor Green
  }
 Else
  {
  Write-Host "Folder $Folder.Folder already exists in $Folder.Path !!!" -ForegroundColor Red -BackGroundColor Black
  }
}
```

And this is my error

> At C:\Scripts\CreateMultipleFoldersWithCheck.ps1:5 char:45
>   +     If(!(Test-Path $Folder.Path\$Folder.Folder))
>   +                                                ~ Missing statement block after If ( condition ). At
>   C:\Scripts\CreateMultipleFoldersWithCheck.ps1:9 char:3
>   +         }
>   +         ~ Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement. At C:\Scripts\CreateMultipleFoldersWithCheck.ps1:14 char:1
>   + }
>   + ~ Unexpected token '}' in expression or statement.
>       + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingStatementBlock

What am I missing?

Comment: Immediately after your If statement you have a closing } rather than an opening {

Comment: Change the incorrect } to a { for starters :)

Answer (score -1):

```
$Folders = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\NewFolders\NewFolders.csv

ForEach ($Folder in $Folders)
{
 If(!(Test-Path $Folder.Path\$Folder.Folder))
  {
  New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Folder.Path\$Folder.Folder
  Write-Host Folder $Folder.Folder created in $Folder.Path ! -ForegroundColor Green
  }
 Else
  {
  Write-Host "Folder $Folder.Folder already exists in $Folder.Path !!!" -ForegroundColor Red -BackGroundColor Black
  }
}
```

You are closing `if statement` istead of opening it,here is your fixed script.

Comment: `$Folders = Import-Csv C:\Scripts\Csv\NewFolders.csv

ForEach ($Folder in $Folders)
{
$Pathname = $Folder.'Path'
$Foldername = $Folder.'Folder'
 If(!(Test-Path $Pathname\$Foldername))
  {
  New-Item -Path $Pathname\$Foldername -ItemType Directory -Force
  Write-Host "$Foldername created in $Pathname !" -ForegroundColor Green
  }
 Else
  {
  Write-Host "Folder $Foldername already exists in $Pathname !!!" -ForegroundColor Red -BackGroundColor Black
  }
}`

I fixed the script with this code. But thanks for the help.